# Removing first non-empty <p> tag from a row

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a few thousands rows which contain HTML data

```
<p>non useful data</p>
<p>useful data</p>
```

I want to remove the first **p** tag

```
<p >non empty</p >
```

and update the row with only

```
<p>useful data</p>
```

I tried

```
$request = mysql_query("select * from content limit 50") or die('Error :'.$request.' '.mysql_error());
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($request)) {
    $id = $r[id];   
    $text = $r[text];   
    preg_match('@<p>.*?</p>(.*)@', $text, $matches);    
    $srcfinal = $matches[1];  
    $srcrestant =$matches[0];    
    echo"$srcfinal<br />";
  }
```

I can correctly extract the unuseful data (`$srcfinal`) but can't find anything to print the needed data (and then update the row with it).

Any lightweight code to use please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to retrieve the rows in PHP, then replace the first `<p>...</p>` tag with an empty string. This will do it (the `\R*` also removes any newline characters after the paragraph):

```
$replaced = preg_replace('%^<p>.*?</p>\R*%', '', $yourstring);
```

I would also consider doing it directly in the database with `UPDATE... SET...`:

- [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) will find your first `</p>`
- [`RIGHT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) will give you the characters to the right of that.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a regular XML / HTML - Parser? There the removal of the first `<p>` tag is no big  deal.

Assuming your result might not conaint valid HTML, you have various options to achieve your goal - be creative :)

- You could simply replace EVERYTING until (and including) the first `</p>` (look at `strpos()` and `substr()`) (http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
- You could split your content at the first occurence of `</p>` (with limit `1` - look at `explode()`) and throw away the first part of the result array. (http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- You could - if your example is correct - simply read the string *line by line* and ommit the first line.

And these are just the options without Regex.